# Selenium Python does not work with Firefox webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of selenium and the Firefox webdriver. The problem is that when using selenium 3.x I get `Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6`, while when using selenium 4.x I get the error `Message: binary is not a Firefox executable`

The code I use is

```
class infoGetter:

    def __init__(self):

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            exit(42)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

I am working in Ubuntu 22 LTS, with Firefox installed as snap. Does anyone know what the problem may be?